# read.csv error more columns than columns name?

Tags: r, csv, dataframe, read.csv

I tried to import data in csv format using read.csv from https://data.worldbank.org/indicator/IS.AIR.PSGR

However, the `read.csv` function gives back:

> Error in `read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,`  : 
>     more columns than column names.

I searched previous posts but it looks like the answers are different case by case by the actual `data tables`, so what's wrong with this one?

Comment: We can't help you until you show us the code you used to try and read it. You should be providing minimal reproducible examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was due to the first 4 lines having random text. You need to use `skip = 4`. Using `read_csv` from `readr` package is better as it preserves original column names.

```r
library(readr)

dat <- read_csv("API_IS.AIR.PSGR_DS2_en_csv_v2.csv", skip = 4)

#> Warning: Missing column names filled in: 'X63' [63]
#> Parsed with column specification:
#> cols(
#>   .default = col_integer(),
#>   `Country Name` = col_character(),
#>   `Country Code` = col_character(),
#>   `Indicator Name` = col_character(),
#>   `Indicator Code` = col_character(),
#>   `1960` = col_character(),
#>   `1961` = col_character(),
#>   `1962` = col_character(),
#>   `1963` = col_character(),
#>   `1964` = col_character(),
#>   `1965` = col_character(),
#>   `1966` = col_character(),
#>   `1967` = col_character(),
#>   `1968` = col_character(),
#>   `1969` = col_character(),
#>   `1995` = col_double(),
#>   `2007` = col_double(),
#>   `2008` = col_double(),
#>   `2009` = col_double(),
#>   `2010` = col_double(),
#>   `2011` = col_double()
#>   # ... with 7 more columns
#> )
#> See spec(...) for full column specifications.

head(dat)

#> # A tibble: 6 x 63
#>   `Country Name` `Country Code` `Indicator Name`   `Indicator Code` `1960`
#>   <chr>          <chr>          <chr>              <chr>            <chr> 
#> 1 Aruba          ABW            Air transport, pa~ IS.AIR.PSGR      <NA>  
#> 2 Afghanistan    AFG            Air transport, pa~ IS.AIR.PSGR      <NA>  
#> 3 Angola         AGO            Air transport, pa~ IS.AIR.PSGR      <NA>  
#> 4 Albania        ALB            Air transport, pa~ IS.AIR.PSGR      <NA>  
#> 5 Andorra        AND            Air transport, pa~ IS.AIR.PSGR      <NA>  
#> 6 Arab World     ARB            Air transport, pa~ IS.AIR.PSGR      <NA>  
#> # ... with 58 more variables: `1961` <chr>, `1962` <chr>, `1963` <chr>,
#> #   `1964` <chr>, `1965` <chr>, `1966` <chr>, `1967` <chr>, `1968` <chr>,
#> #   `1969` <chr>, `1970` <int>, `1971` <int>, `1972` <int>, `1973` <int>,
#> #   `1974` <int>, `1975` <int>, `1976` <int>, `1977` <int>, `1978` <int>,
#> #   `1979` <int>, `1980` <int>, `1981` <int>, `1982` <int>, `1983` <int>,
#> #   `1984` <int>, `1985` <int>, `1986` <int>, `1987` <int>, `1988` <int>,
#> #   `1989` <int>, `1990` <int>, `1991` <int>, `1992` <int>, `1993` <int>,
#> #   `1994` <int>, `1995` <dbl>, `1996` <int>, `1997` <int>, `1998` <int>,
#> #   `1999` <int>, `2000` <int>, `2001` <int>, `2002` <int>, `2003` <int>,
#> #   `2004` <int>, `2005` <int>, `2006` <int>, `2007` <dbl>, `2008` <dbl>,
#> #   `2009` <dbl>, `2010` <dbl>, `2011` <dbl>, `2012` <dbl>, `2013` <dbl>,
#> #   `2014` <dbl>, `2015` <dbl>, `2016` <dbl>, `2017` <chr>, X63 <chr>
```

Created on 2018-03-05 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue while running through docker. So, I had to download the file first then read csv file.

```
# download data
download.file("https://data.worldbank.org/indicator/IS.AIR.PSGR", dest = "file.csv")

# load data
gm = read.table("file.csv", header = T, stringsAsFactors = F, skipNul = F)
```